# How to dynamically create a React component based on url param?

Tags: reactjs, parameters, react-router

I'd like my React component to generate based on the url param, in this case, the :id param. I'm struggling rendering the component. I have the different Components defined in separate files (ex. Loader.js, Radio button.js, Accordion menu.js).

Here's my (reduced for clarity) code that is continuously failing :)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Grid from '../Components/Grid'

function Overview () {
  const components = [
    {id: 'accordion-menu',
    name: 'Accordion menu'},
    {id: 'radio-button',
    name: 'Radio button'},
    {id: 'loader',
    name: 'Loader'},
      ]

  const componentPage = ({match}) => {
    const findId = components.find((el) => {
      match.params.id = el.id;
        return findId.name;
      }
    )}
      
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="components">
    <h3>Components</h3>
      <p>This header and the menu will always appear on this page!</p>
      <menu>
        {components.map(({id, name}) => (
          <li>
            <Link to={`/components/${id}`}>{name}</Link>
          </li> 
          
        ))}
      </menu>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={'/components/'} component={Grid}/>
          <Route path={'/components/:id'} component={componentPage}/>
        </Switch>
    </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default Overview;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const componentPage = ({match}) => {
    const findId = components.find((el) => {
      match.params.id = el.id;
        return findId.name;
      }
    )}
```

I think what you mean here is  to return el.name not findId.name.

the other thing is you are trying to display the function as a component which won't work.

Comment: hm... how can I display the result of el.name as a component, so the correct component is rendered?